# how playframework trigger a logined user logout when the user's flag is set to disabled

Tags: playframework

managers(admin, user) can loign a web application, when admin disabled a user who is logined how to trigger the user logout the application right now?

I wonder in playframework how to trigger a logined user logout.

Comment: I want to to set the logined user's session to null to logout the user, but can't get the user's session id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to go about this is to have a controller action annotated with @Before, that checks that the user's status (i.e. has been logged out by an admin) and if the user has been logged out redirects them to an appropriate page.

Example

```
@Before
private static void checkUserIsStillLoggedIn() {
    // do some logic to check the user is logged out by admin
    // ...
    // if has been logged out, redirect to the login page, rather than continuing
    if (hasBeenLoggedOut) login();
}
```

Comment: this method need check user's status every time, and most of the check is useless and will waste lot of time, is there something that can trigger check, like job's now.

Comment: not really, because the server holds no client state, apart from the DB. Job.now() would not know who to communicate with that the users status has changed, unless you have websockets and store some server side state as part of the long living communication. but, this is probably overkill.

Comment: I solved this by put login info cache in System, when user's status changed, change the cache, then when check user is still logged in, just logout. LOGIN_INFO = (HashMap<String, Integer>)Cache.get("LOGIN_INFO"); is enough. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just call a function in which you wrote your logout logic of a controller. Because all the methods of controller are static, so they can be called in any static function. For Example

```
public class Authentication extends JapidController {

    public static void logout() {
          //logic of logout
        }
}  


public class ApplicationController extends JapidController {
    @Before
    static void checkAuthenticated() {
        //if user is disabled by admin {
             Authentication.logout();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling a static Controller method causes a redirect to that page rather then calling it. If you need a method to be called directly, you have to use @Util - Annotation to mark it as "not an action".

Comment: I can't get the user's session(Cache), and don't know if this user is logined. how let the user logout?